# Web request to 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token' failed. No connection could be ...target machine actively refused it 173.194.70.84:443

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am building an application to fetch data via google analytics. For that purpose I have created a service account information from Google API console and in my .NET webform application successfully able to fetch data via following code:

```
string clientEmailId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("clientEmailId");
string keyFile = AnalyticsKeyFileInitialPath + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("keyFile");
string keyPass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("keyPass");
var desc = GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description;
var key = new X509Certificate2(keyFile, keyPass, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var client = new AssertionFlowClient(desc, key) { ServiceAccountId = clientEmailId, Scope = scopeUrl };
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(client, AssertionFlowClient.GetState);
var gas = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    Authenticator = auth
});
//auth.LoadAccessToken();
var accounts = gas.Management.Accounts.List().Fetch();
```

Now I am calling same code via WCF service but getting following error

> Exception Message: Unable to connect to the remote server
>   Inner Exception:   Web request to 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token' failed.
>   Inner Exception:   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 173.194.70.84:443

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Strangest behavior i have observe.
When i put the use the Use Visual Studio Development Server generated url in the endpoint of the calling program it works like charm.
But when I use virtual directory or Web Application in IIS and put that address it throws the same error.
Any idea what can be the problem.

Comment: Find out it is due to some firewall issue on developer machine. Still not able to find out which particular restriction i will remove so that i will not face this problem [not wanting to remove firewall restriction on whole]